# Decoding JSON data leads to "invalid control character" error

Tags: python, json

```
import json
people_string = '''
{
    "People": [
        {
            "name": "John Smith",
            "phone": "615-555-7164",
            "emails": ["johnsmith@bogusemail.com", "john.smith@workplace.com"],
            "Has license": false
        },
        {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "phone": "560-555-5153",
            "emails": null,
            "Has license: true
        }
    ]
 }
'''
data = json.loads(people_string)
```

When I try to run this, I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Jorge87\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Jorge87\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Jorge87\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at: line 14 column 31 (char 361)
```

I also tried importing simplejson instead, but still doesn´t work.

How can I fix this? What does these error messages mean?

Comment: The above json is not valid, "Has license" key in second item in People list needs a quotation mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your error message:

```
ValueError: Invalid control character at: line 14 column 31 (char 361)
```

you can see your error is here:

```
>>> print(people_string.splitlines()[13] + '\n' + ' '*30 + '^')
            "Has license: true
                              ^
```

Where it sees a newline instead of a ".
You forgot a closing double quote for `"Has license"`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a quotation mark in "Has licence", thats it:

```
"Has license": true
```

instead of:

```
"Has license: true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "phone": "560-555-5153",
        "emails": null,
        "Has license: true
    }
```

It looks like your Has license key is missing a closing double quotation mark.